# How can I make a text "pop out" with an effect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've searched a lot in google to find a way to animate a text on my HTML site with the help of JavaScript. 
So my idea is when someone opens my website I want to zoom a text element to create a pop out effect to visualize that this text is interactive with the mouse (Clickable, changeable, whatever...).

Do you know if there exists a function which can animate my text this way? I just want to show this effect once so I don't want to repeat it. This is the text I want to animate:

```html
<p class="info-text">Das ist mein Text welcher einen Pop-out effect benötigt</p>
```

**Solution**
 
Big thanks to Nikita! This is the working solution:

```css
.my-text {
  animation: pop 0.4s ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes pop {
  50%  {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="my-text">Hello everyone :)</p>
```

Comment: Can you show an example online that behaves in a way you wish to replicate?

Comment: Here are some examples: https://codepen.io/Jtwa/pen/dYvLpN

Comment: @Frish The pop animation looks right. How can I implement this that when I open my website that the text pop up this way only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pop animation exactly when page loads, just add a class for the element with text. And in CSS write needed animation. And after the page loads, the popup animation will play and play once.

```
<div class="pop"></div>
<div class="pop with-delay"></div>
```

and add styles (if you want to add some delay, in css/styles add "animation-delay"):

```
.pop{
  animation: pop 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.with-delay {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes pop{
  50%  {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
}
```

Here's example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQGBdm

Comment: Forgot to add, that javacsript isn't necessary here. It's easier and better to use given functionality.

Comment: Nikita thats brilliant. I also thought that js is needed here. I've tried it out and looks great. So now you're a part of my website :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it is called onload method : you cando something basic like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1 id="title">Hello World!</h1>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Page is loaded");
  //example
document.getElementById("title").style.color = "blue";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

or you can use jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//change the css
});
```

this is the basic way, 
but next time you need to show examples of things that you've tried before when you ask a question

Comment: Thanks for trying it :) Vote up for your helpfulness,